Object constraints are behaving differently from tutorial settings
I'm seeing a tutorial on animating tank treads, I have the same object constraint values, but my object is behaving differently when I try to move it. When I try to move it on the Y axis, its moving diagonally. And I can see the bezierCircle pop out of its location when I try to rotate it on its Z axis.





pls also link the tutorial. thx.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2A363iHacQ&t=775s
Rigging the treads starts at: 08:55sec.
Thank you.

You've given a Child Of constraint to your object, you could also have parented to the empty but there might be a reason why you're using this contraint. Anyway the problem is that you've not enabled the Y location so the object won't follow the empty correctly:


The disabling of the Y axis is crucial to the rigging method Ryan shows in his tutorial, without disabling it the treads don't move around the curve.

Oh ok i missed that so I'm not sure how he wants to do it

Actually this disabling is one of the reasons why he cannot use simple parenting. I did the tutorial once and got it to work, however I changed a few things to make it better, but still both methods had their flaws. Although Ryan shows that they move correctly they do just to a certain extent which I could not resolve either. Right now I cannot look into the file what is wrong with blender breath's version compared to the tutorial, maybe later.

yes i never realized there was this problem

actually you can move the object on its own local axis only and it won't drift away, but he probably trying to create something automatic? https://zupimages.net/up/24/24/5013.gif

That's not how tank treads work  For turning left for example the left side usually has to drive backwards and the right side forwards, standing still while rotating around the Z axis is not correct.

yes I just meant that I would do it manually rather than automatically   ;)

Well, no the point of the tutorial is actually doing it automatically, having a tank model moving as you desire and making the treads follow according to it as if they were moving the tank.

Sure, it was my mistake when I wrote the answer, for an automatic setting I don't know how to do it   ;)

Well, I guess the main issue here is not to come up with a new solution but just to find out what is done differently to the tutorial since the results differ. But my recommendation is usually just to follow the tutorial more thoroughly as there is obviously something he did not pay enough attention to.
